# Error with zookeeper & storm

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I am developing a code for Storm, which is an example of the developers. My problem is that when you run this code from IDE Eclipse, do not get the connection between Storm and Zookeeper is established. Zookeeper is running in 2181 and is also set in storm.yaml.

My exception is:

```
72992 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - caught end of stream exception
org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15432be39f50004, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_67]
73194 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:37597 which had sessionid 0x15432be39f50004
```

Any idea or procedure to be performed? Pass from the configuration code? And as I do?

Comment: If you run in an IDE you should use `LocalCluster` which does not need an external ZK running.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in the past,when I was beggining with Storm. I'm not an expert yet, but I can afford to say that @Matthias J. Sax is right, the topology must run in local-mode to start it on Eclipse. I did that with Eclipse Mars, running Storm 0.10.0 and worked perfect. You have to do this:

Replace:

```
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("test", conf, builder.createTopology());
```

With:

```
 LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
      cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, builder.createTopology());
```

Hope it helped you.